# Python "'dict' object has no attribute 'savetofile'"

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

py, two.py

**One.py**

```
two.savetofile(profil)
```

**two.py**

```
def savetofile(profil):

   print profil
```

*Profil is here*

```
{'jozeef': {'stredaz': None, 'utorokz': None, 'pondelokz': '22', 'stvrtokz': None, 'utorokk': None, 'pondelokk': '22', 'stvrtokk': None, 'sobotaz': None, 'piatokk': None, 'nedelak': None, 'sobotak': None, 'nedelaz': None, 'piatokz': None}}
```

What is the wrong Please ?

**Ansever Andriy Ivaneyko, It was  Solution**

Comment: please provide a properly indented [mcve]

Comment: Given that the word `function` appears no where in your code or input, it's impossible to say what it going on here.

Comment: Hi I have complex code. I create simple 
example my  problem. Jean-François Fabre

Comment: Given an answer, please provide more details on the error you faced.

Comment: You've simplified so much you've made the problem go away. Show enough code to actually reproduce the issue.

Comment: I agree chepner. I edit questions

Comment: do you import `two` at some point in `one.py`? how do you do it? find a place in `one.py` where `two` is defined or imported

Comment: Thank you for trying  Juraj Bezručka. I have now solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess that you have defined an variable with name `two` which is dictinary, so you have name collision ( variable and module have same name) which  shall be avoided by renaming variable or updating the way you have imported module.

```
import two as two_module

two_module.savetofile(profil)
```

Comment: Andriy Ivaneyko Thanks very much.
Very help me. It is sulutions my problem

Comment: @user7432329 you are welcome, please mark answer as accepted to make your question 'answered'